# how to limit and order by in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm familiar with MySQL but not in MS SQL,

In MySQL the query will be like this:

```
SELECT * from tablename ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

The above query gives a 5 random number of result from the table. The same query how can i do with MS SQL?

Comment: Tell me if I am wrong. I think the 'Order by' clausel is used for sorting the result record set.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try,

```
SELECT TOP 5 * from tablename ORDER BY NEWID()
```

- [NEWID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at using [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) and order by [NEWID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx)

Something like

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM TableName 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM tablename
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Tested in MSSQL 2005.